# Focus Issue with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select option that upon clicking, it changes a form attribute from `display: none` to `display: block`, and changes the windows.hash to something else, however in Chrome the view automatically scrolls down and focuses the form.  How do you prevent this behavior?

```
function mainTypeChange(element){
    if ("business" == element.options[element.selectedIndex].value) {
        window.location.hash = "business";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("requestQuote").style.display = 'block';    
        window.location.hash = "requestQuote";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you'll find `pushState` helpful. See the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Comment: It automatically scrolls because you changed its hash value, hash here represents the fragment that you want to navigate to, it is the part in an URL that starts with the `#` sign. To prevent it you can insert `return false;`

Comment: when you bind event on the link as `<href url="#"></href>`, please remember to use `e.preventDefault();`. ex: `$(element).on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); //Do you work here// ;})`